# SVG animation issue. SVG moves after animation ends

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I've run into an issue when animating an SVG on hover. When you move the cursor away when the animation is done you can see the arrowheads move slightly by a pixel or two. Anyone know how to have them not move?

I am only animating the opacity of the arrowheads so I'm not sure why they shift.

Stack overflow wants me to add more details, but I've added all that I can to describe the problem, so I am just typing more words. Thanks for the help.

```css
svg:hover .woven .st0 {
  animation: offset 1.5s linear forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
svg:hover .woven .st1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: opacity 1.5s linear forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@keyframes offset {
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 50;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 60;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1442.3 836.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1442.3 836.8;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:none;stroke:#262322;stroke-width:2.0359;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st1{fill:#262322;}
 .st2{fill:#C73130;stroke:#C73130;stroke-width:4.3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g id="Layer_1" class="woven">
 <g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="237.8" y1="680" x2="197.9" y2="719.9"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M200.8,703.2c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C200.1,703.2,200.5,703.1,200.8,703.2z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="236.5" y1="681.3" x2="276.4" y2="641.4"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M273.5,658.2c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3s0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C274.2,658.1,273.8,658.2,273.5,658.2z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="236.9" y1="682.1" x2="197" y2="642.2"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M213.7,645.1c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9c0.2-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C213.7,644.4,213.8,644.7,213.7,645.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="235.5" y1="680.7" x2="275.5" y2="720.7"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M258.7,717.7c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9c-0.2,0.2-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C258.8,718.4,258.6,718.1,258.7,717.7z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="118.3" y1="591.7" x2="78.4" y2="631.6"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M81.3,614.9c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C80.6,614.9,80.9,614.8,81.3,614.9z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="116.9" y1="593" x2="156.9" y2="553.1"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M153.9,569.9c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8s0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C154.6,569.8,154.3,569.9,153.9,569.9z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="117.4" y1="593.8" x2="77.4" y2="553.8"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M94.2,556.8c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2s-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       L75.4,553c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3C94.1,556.1,94.3,556.4,94.2,556.8z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="116" y1="592.4" x2="155.9" y2="632.3"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M139.2,629.4c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C139.2,630.1,139.1,629.8,139.2,629.4z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="118.3" y1="415.3" x2="78.4" y2="455.2"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M81.3,438.4c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8s-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5C80.6,438.5,80.9,438.4,81.3,438.4z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="116.9" y1="416.6" x2="156.9" y2="376.7"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M153.9,393.4c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8s0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3s0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5C154.6,393.4,154.3,393.5,153.9,393.4z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="117.4" y1="417.4" x2="77.4" y2="377.4"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M94.2,380.4c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2s-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3C94.1,379.7,94.3,380,94.2,380.4z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="116" y1="416" x2="155.9" y2="455.9"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M139.2,453c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C139.2,453.7,139.1,453.4,139.2,453z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="118.3" y1="245.4" x2="78.4" y2="285.3"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M81.3,268.5c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2L78.7,285l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5C80.6,268.6,80.9,268.5,81.3,268.5z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="116.9" y1="246.7" x2="156.9" y2="206.8"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M153.9,223.5c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C154.6,223.5,154.3,223.6,153.9,223.5z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="117.4" y1="247.5" x2="77.4" y2="207.5"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M94.2,210.5c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C94.1,209.8,94.3,210.1,94.2,210.5z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="116" y1="246.1" x2="155.9" y2="286"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M139.2,283.1c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C139.2,283.8,139.1,283.4,139.2,283.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="237.8" y1="504.1" x2="197.9" y2="544"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M200.8,527.3c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C200.1,527.3,200.5,527.2,200.8,527.3z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="236.5" y1="505.4" x2="276.4" y2="465.5"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M273.5,482.3c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3s0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C274.2,482.2,273.8,482.3,273.5,482.3z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="236.9" y1="506.2" x2="197" y2="466.2"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M213.7,469.2c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C213.7,468.5,213.8,468.8,213.7,469.2z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="235.5" y1="504.8" x2="275.5" y2="544.7"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M258.7,541.8c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C258.8,542.5,258.6,542.2,258.7,541.8z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="237.8" y1="328" x2="197.9" y2="367.9"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M200.8,351.1c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C200.1,351.2,200.5,351.1,200.8,351.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="236.5" y1="329.3" x2="276.4" y2="289.4"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M273.5,306.1c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3s0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C274.2,306.1,273.8,306.2,273.5,306.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="236.9" y1="330" x2="197" y2="290.1"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M213.7,293c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C213.7,292.3,213.8,292.7,213.7,293z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="235.5" y1="328.7" x2="275.5" y2="368.6"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M258.7,365.7c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C258.8,366.4,258.6,366,258.7,365.7z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="237.8" y1="151.9" x2="197.9" y2="191.9"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M200.8,175.1c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C200.1,175.1,200.5,175,200.8,175.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="236.5" y1="153.3" x2="276.4" y2="113.4"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M273.5,130.1c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C274.2,130.1,273.8,130.2,273.5,130.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="236.9" y1="154" x2="197" y2="114.1"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M213.7,117c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9c0.2-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C213.7,116.3,213.8,116.7,213.7,117z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="235.5" y1="152.7" x2="275.5" y2="192.6"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M258.7,189.7c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C258.8,190.4,258.6,190,258.7,189.7z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <circle class="st2" cx="117.1" cy="681" r="7.9"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="117.1" cy="505.1" r="7.9"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="117.1" cy="329" r="7.9"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="117.1" cy="153" r="7.9"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="236.7" cy="768.9" r="7.9"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="236.7" cy="592.7" r="7.9"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="236.7" cy="416.3" r="7.9"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="236.7" cy="65" r="7.9"/>
  <circle class="st2" cx="236.7" cy="246.4" r="7.9"/>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="476.9" y1="680" x2="437" y2="719.9"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M439.9,703.2c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C439.2,703.2,439.6,703.1,439.9,703.2z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="475.6" y1="681.3" x2="515.5" y2="641.4"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M512.6,658.2c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3s0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C513.3,658.1,512.9,658.2,512.6,658.2z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="476" y1="682.1" x2="436.1" y2="642.2"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M452.8,645.1c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2s-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9c0.2-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C452.8,644.4,452.9,644.7,452.8,645.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="474.6" y1="680.7" x2="514.6" y2="720.7"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M497.8,717.7c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9c-0.2,0.2-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C497.8,718.4,497.7,718.1,497.8,717.7z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="357.4" y1="591.7" x2="317.4" y2="631.6"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M320.4,614.9c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C319.7,614.9,320,614.8,320.4,614.9z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="356" y1="593" x2="395.9" y2="553.1"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M393,569.9c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C393.7,569.8,393.4,569.9,393,569.9z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="356.4" y1="593.8" x2="316.5" y2="553.8"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M333.3,556.8c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C333.2,556.1,333.3,556.4,333.3,556.8z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="355.1" y1="592.4" x2="395" y2="632.3"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M378.3,629.4c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C378.3,630.1,378.2,629.8,378.3,629.4z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="357.4" y1="415.3" x2="317.4" y2="455.2"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M320.4,438.4c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C319.7,438.5,320,438.4,320.4,438.4z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="356" y1="416.6" x2="395.9" y2="376.7"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M393,393.4c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3s0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C393.7,393.4,393.4,393.5,393,393.4z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="356.4" y1="417.4" x2="316.5" y2="377.4"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M333.3,380.4c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C333.2,379.7,333.3,380,333.3,380.4z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="355.1" y1="416" x2="395" y2="455.9"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M378.3,453c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2s1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3C378.3,453.7,378.2,453.4,378.3,453z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="357.4" y1="245.4" x2="317.4" y2="285.3"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M320.4,268.5c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C319.7,268.6,320,268.5,320.4,268.5z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="356" y1="246.7" x2="395.9" y2="206.8"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M393,223.5c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C393.7,223.5,393.4,223.6,393,223.5z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="356.4" y1="247.5" x2="316.5" y2="207.5"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M333.3,210.5c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C333.2,209.8,333.3,210.1,333.3,210.5z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="355.1" y1="246.1" x2="395" y2="286"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M378.3,283.1c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2s1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3C378.3,283.8,378.2,283.4,378.3,283.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="476.9" y1="504.1" x2="437" y2="544"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M439.9,527.3c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8
       c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5
       C439.2,527.3,439.6,527.2,439.9,527.3z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="475.6" y1="505.4" x2="515.5" y2="465.5"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M512.6,482.3c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3s0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C513.3,482.2,512.9,482.3,512.6,482.3z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="476" y1="506.2" x2="436.1" y2="466.2"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M452.8,469.2c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3L452,468c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C452.8,468.5,452.9,468.8,452.8,469.2z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="474.6" y1="504.8" x2="514.6" y2="544.7"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M497.8,541.8c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C497.8,542.5,497.7,542.2,497.8,541.8z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="476.9" y1="328" x2="437" y2="367.9"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M439.9,351.1c0.5,0.1,0.9,0.7,0.8,1.2l-3.4,15.2l15.2-3.4c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8s-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       l-16.8,3.7c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0-0.9-0.3s-0.3-0.6-0.3-0.9l3.7-16.8c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.5C439.2,351.2,439.6,351.1,439.9,351.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="475.6" y1="329.3" x2="515.5" y2="289.4"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M512.6,306.1c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.7-0.8-1.2l3.4-15.2l-15.2,3.4c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8
       c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2l16.8-3.7c0.3-0.1,0.7,0,0.9,0.3s0.3,0.6,0.3,0.9l-3.7,16.8c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5
       C513.3,306.1,512.9,306.2,512.6,306.1z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="476" y1="330" x2="436.1" y2="290.1"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M452.8,293c-0.1,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.2,0.8l-15.2-3.4l3.4,15.2c0.1,0.5-0.2,1.1-0.8,1.2
       c-0.5,0.1-1.1-0.2-1.2-0.8l-3.7-16.8c-0.1-0.3,0-0.7,0.3-0.9s0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3l16.8,3.7c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.3
       C452.8,292.3,452.9,292.7,452.8,293z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="474.6" y1="328.7" x2="514.6" y2="368.6"/>
     <g>
      <path class="st1" d="M497.8,365.7c0.1-0.5,0.7-0.9,1.2-0.8l15.2,3.4l-3.4-15.2c-0.1-0.5,0.2-1.1,0.8-1.2
       c0.5-0.1,1.1,0.2,1.2,0.8l3.7,16.8c0.1,0.3,0,0.7-0.3,0.9s-0.6,0.3-0.9,0.3l-16.8-3.7c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.3
       C497.8,366.4,497.7,366,497.8,365.7z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
<g id="Layer_2">
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a bug in Chrome.  It doesn't seem to happen in Firefox.

It looks like it's perhaps a compositing error. The arrowheads are moving slightly to the left when their opacity becomes 1.

I would recommend you [report it to Chrome](http://crbug.com), and then please post the bug number here for the benefit of other readers.